# How to make Soundpool load lots of short sounds?

Tags: android, stream, soundpool

I got advice that I should use Soundpool instead of Mediaplayer for lot of short sounds on button click but I don't really understand how to make it work. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle buttons) {
    super.onCreate(buttons);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    //SoundPool initialization somewhere
    SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    //Load your sound effect into the pool
    int soundId = pool.load(this, R.raw.SOUND, 1); (How to load more sounds?)

    List<Integer> streams = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Button PLAY= (Button)findViewById(R.id.PLAY);
    PLAY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int streamId = pool.play(SOUND, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            streams.add(streamId);
        }
    });

    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (Integer stream : streams) {
                 pool.stop(stream);
            }
            streams.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

1. My code doesn't work. Please edit the code and post it to answers.
2. I want to load more sounds. How?
3. Is there any explanation video on youtube?

Comment: whats the first param of pool.play?

Comment: Its soundID i think.

Comment: and what's "int soundId = pool.load(..."  and how is it related to SOUND variable?

Comment: even though i match int soundID with the first param in pool.play it says that  the .add in streams.add(streamId) : "cannot resolve method"

Comment: i don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Write me a working code based on that mine.

Comment: Use google,  there is a lot of pages about SoundPool

Comment: I tried with no results that would help me, now if you would be so kind and fix my bugs in the code? :)